# Where is the data stored in the XMLHttpRequest() POST request? Read on Node.js Server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send data via an XML POST Request to Node.js server and read the data and send an appropriate response back to the client? However, I've been unable to access the request.body value? Is there an issue with the code?

I've tried various console.logs of the request data and cannot locate it?

HTML Client-Side

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", '/view/translation', true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
        // Request finished. Do processing here.
        console.log(xhr.responseText)
    }
}   
xhr.send("data= 'kdjkkafjdkajs'");
// xhr.send(new Int8Array()); 
// xhr.send(document);
```

NODE.JS  Server-side

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();


 const bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }));

 router.post('/translation', (request, response) => {
 const data = request.body; //<---

 console.log(data)
  response.json('Hello'+ data);//<--
  })
```

console.log(data) on the server-side returns -->  {}
browser returns --> ---> [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT

So looking back retrospectively on this "xhr.send("data= 'kdjkkafjdkajs'");" this is not how you write a XML REQUEST.

This should be:

xhr.send("data=kdjkkafjdkajs");

or with more options and using variable data:

xhr.send("uid="+usr_num+"&l="+learn);

this is subsequently available in req.body.uid ect..

Using in node.js:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '20mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

---

Okay so the issue has been discovered, I was working within a module and didn't realize that express was using :

app.use(express.json({ limit: '1mb' }));

for any incoming requests.